# Does presenceOfElementLocated not handle Stale DOM elements?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was attempting to wait until an overlay cleared from a page load using presenceOfElementLocated. However it never detected that the overlay was gone (removed from DOM). I can only deduct this had something to do with DOM staleness? The numberOfElementsToBe did work. Which seems strange but if it's querying the DOM fresh, makes total sense.

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait
    .withMessage("Loading Overlay never disappeared")
//this didn't work
    .until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("overlay"))));
//this worked
  .until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBe(By.className("overlay"),0));
```

Is this an ok way to test for stale DOM preventing you from properly waiting on dom removals? Or do I need to change my presenceOfElementLocated check?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for overlay to disappear, you can implement [`invisibilityOfElementLocated`](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2014/02/how-to-apply-wait-in-webdriver-till.html) condition as below:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("overlay")));
```

Comment: Except it had the same problem as presence. The Dom doesn't realize the element has been removed.